# GL.GetError() affects where errors are returned or not

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm doing some experiments with OpenTK and C#. The below code is using OpenTK syntax but it's from what I understand just a thin wrapper around OpenGL. I'm using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4.

In `OnRenderFrame`, I do this:

```
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.DrawFramebuffer, _buffer);
var err1 = GL.GetError();

GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, _textureHandle);
var err2= GL.GetError();

GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, TextureTarget.Texture2D, _textureHandle, 0);
var err3 = GL.GetError();
```

Both _buffer and _textureHandle are integers.

This runs fine and both `err1`, `err2`, and `err3` are `NoError`.

However, if I comment out `err1` and `err2`, I get `INVALID_OPERATION` on `err3`. If I leave only `err1` or `err2`, they are both `NoError`. If I remove all error checking, the game runs fine, so the error does not seem to be fatal in any way. Although if I want to check for errors later in the program, that INVALID_OPERATION lingers in the queue so it gets reported then instead.

So it seems that just checking for errors after `GBindFrameBuffer` and `BindTexture` prevents `FrameBufferTexture2D` from generating an error, but if I don't check for errors before that, I get errors on `FrameBufferTexture2D`.

How can this happen? Is it some kind of timing issue?

Comment: Not sure why querying errors makes a difference, but are you sure that you want to bind the framebuffer to `DrawFramebuffer`, when you later want to access it via `Framebuffer`?

Comment: are you sure it doesn't come from an earlier operation? I can see that if you wrote `if(err3 != NoError) crashTheGame();` then you might get the exact results you are reporting, because if there was some error during initialization, and err3 was the moment it was first checked, the game would crash, but if you also uncommented err1 or err2, the error would be reported there and the game would not crash, and then on the next frame, they would all be NoError and maybe you would think there was never any error.

Comment: This is all on the very first frame when I boot the app. So if it was from some earlier operation I would expect err1 to report an error, right?

Comment: @BDL No, I'm not sure and I can't say I 100% know what I'm doing. I changed it to FrameBuffer instead and that seems to work just as well :)